# CocoaPods - iOS, add new OSX target, not linking properly?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

I've got an iOS app, that now needs an osx build. As it's 80%-ish shared code I've added an OSX build to the project.

With my cocoapods I'm getting a few build errors (after pod install, also tried pod update)
Also found I had explicitly add a pod to the osx target to get it do the link and build phase magic in the workspace file.

The first and key error:

```
Target 'Pods-scoreosx' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_scoreosx.framework' because it doesn't contain platform 'macosx' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'iphonesimulator, iphoneos'
```

Any one know what I'm doing wrong?

edit:
Current Podspec file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'EmitterKit'
pod 'SwiftDate'
pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
pod 'ReactiveKit', '~> 1.0'
pod 'ReactiveUIKit', '~> 1.0'
pod 'ReactiveFoundation', '~> 1.0'
pod 'AsyncSwift'

target 'score' do

end

target 'scoreTests' do

end

target 'scoreUITests' do

end

target 'scoreosx' do
    pod 'EmitterKit'
end

target 'scoreosxTests' do

end

target 'scoreosxUITests' do

end
```

Comment: Would you show us the podspec?

Comment: Sure can - annnnd edited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says you need to explicitly configure the platform for the target. Setting declaring the platform in the target would help.

```
target 'scoreosx' do
    platform :osx
    pod 'EmitterKit'
end
```